# Ускорение генерации excel файла на c#

Tags: c#, excel

Ситуация следующая:

Необходимо из набора данных (порядка 7000 значений) сгенерировать отчет. Структура отчета задается шаблоном (набор стандартных блоков и порядок значений в строках блока, количество строк в блоке и количество заполняемых ячеек варьируется), ячейки в которые необходимо вставить данные ищутся поиском по ключевому тексту для значения. После вставки данных незаполненные ячейки очищаются (тот же поиск, но вставка пустого текста, а не значений). Вставка занимает в среднем 87с., удаление 33с. Есть варианты ускорить работу приложения?

Код примерно следующий:

```
foreach(значения)
{
   rngFind = rngReport.Find(Ключевой текст, Type.Missing, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, 
Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false, Type.Missing, false);
   if (rngFind != null)
   {
      rngFind.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;
      rngFind.Value2 = Значение;
   }
}


while (flag)
{
   rngFind = rngReport.Find(Элемент ключа, rngReport.Cells[1, 1],  Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
                              Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false, Type.Missing, false);
   if (rngFind != null)
   {
      rngFind.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;
      rngFind.Value2 = "";
   }
}
```

Дополнение:

Ускорит ли работу вариант со сбором значений в массив по шаблону, а потом уже вставкой массива в excel без поиска, просто по тем же индексам что в массиве?

Дополнение2:
Добавление в код следующих строк ускорило работу на 13%:

```
xlApp.Calculation = Excel.XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual;
xlApp.ScreenUpdating = false;
```

Заметки: Calculation можно изменить только при открытом документе и ручной расчет влияет на доступность буфера обмена (при дефолтном значении во время генерации документа нельзя было что-то скопировать в windows).

Для ускорения работы с данными можно работать с массивом вместо Range (`Object[,] vals = (System.Object[,])wsReport.Cells.get_Range(from, to)`), но так не получается сохранять форматирование из шаблона, как обойтись без Range, но сохранить форматирование?

Похожее обсуждение на [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356371/excel-interop-efficiency-and-performance).
Статья на [microsoft.com](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302096/ru) по работе с массивом вместо range.

Дополнение 3:
Удалось сравнить Interop и EPPlus (3.0.0.2) на генерации одинаковых документов: Interop медленнее в ~20 раз.

Comment: Может, работать с Excel через Xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Делай как я:

```
Object[,] vals = (System.Object[,])wsReport.get_Range(from, to).get_Value(Type.Missing);
```

В этом массиве набираются и изменяются итоговые данные.

```
Excel.Range format = wsReport.Cells.get_Range(from, to);
```

Этот range используется для вставки форматов из шаблонов.

При получении блока из шаблона (rng) делаю так:

```
rng.Copy(Type.Missing);//скопировали в буфер
((Excel.Range)format[fromRow, 1]).PasteSpecial(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteFormats, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);//скопировали форматирование из шаблона на итоговый лист

Object[,] tmpvals = (Object[,])rng.get_Value(Type.Missing);//взяли значения из шаблона, теперь надо вставить в итоговый массив данных
for (int i = 1; i <= rng.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (fromRow > vals.GetUpperBound(0)) break;
    for (int j = 1; j<= rng.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        vals[fromRow, j] = tmpvals[i,j];
    }
    fromRow++;//курсор на последнюю строчку
}
```

Вместо Find приходится делать так:

```
foreach (значения)
{
    for (int i = nRows - dx; i <= nRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 2; j < vals.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
        {
             if (vals[i,j]!=null && vals[i, j].ToString() == ключевой текст)
             {
                 vals[i, j] = значение;
                 goto Found;
             }
        }
    }
Found: ;
}
```

В итоге время формирования документа со 150с. (вставка строк 0.6с, вставка значений 86с., удаление 32с.) уменьшилось до 45с (вставка строк 13с. вставка данных в массив 0.13с., удаление 0.32с, итоговая вставка 0.16).